# Check if an object belongs to a class in Java

Tags: java, polymorphism

Is there an easy way to verify that an object belongs to a given class? For example, I could do

```
if(a.getClass() = (new MyClass()).getClass())
{
    //do something
}
```

but this requires instantiating a new object on the fly each time, only to discard it. Is there a better way to check that "a" belongs to the class "MyClass"?

Answer (score 209, accepted):

The `instanceof` keyword, as described by the other answers, is usually what you would want. 
Keep in mind that `instanceof` will return `true` for superclasses as well.

If you want to see if an object is a direct instance of a class, you could compare the class. You can get the class object of an instance via `getClass()`. And you can statically access a specific class via `ClassName.class`.

So for example:

```
if (a.getClass() == X.class) {
  // do something
}
```

In the above example, the condition is true if `a` is an instance of `X`, but not if `a` is an instance of a subclass of `X`.

In comparison:

```
if (a instanceof X) {
    // do something
  }
```

In the `instanceof` example, the condition is true if `a` is an instance of `X`, or if `a` is an instance of a **subclass** of `X`.

Most of the time, `instanceof` is right.

Answer (score 35):

If you ever need to do this dynamically, you can use the following:

```
boolean isInstance(Object object, Class<?> type) {
    return type.isInstance(object);
}
```

You can get an instance of [`java.lang.Class`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) by calling the instance method `Object::getClass` on any object (returns the `Class` which that object is an instance of), or you can use class literals (for example, `String.class`, `List.class`, `int[].class`). There are other ways as well, through the reflection API (which `Class` itself is the entry point for).

Comment: or better yet, use IsAssignableFrom(Class)

Comment: @Chii But then you need to call `getClass` on `a` again, which is what thebackhand was trying to avoid.

Comment: no - all you need is references to the classes you want to compare - a.getClass().isAssignableFrom(MyClass.class) , or the other way around.

Comment: @Chii That's assuming he knows what class he wants to compare to ahead of time. My answer was for doing it dynamically.

Comment: Does this work for inherited objects as well ? Like if class ```Sub``` derives from ```Super``` and in a method, the signature is ```method(Super super)``` then if I evaluate ```super isinstanceof Sub```, will it work if an object of type ```Sub``` is passed as a parameter to this method ?

Comment: @AritroShome If I'm understanding your question correctly, then yes, that will work. You can test this easily with jshell.

Comment: @gdejohn Yeah, thanks. I guess in this era of IDEs, I tend to forget tools like ```jshell``` !

Answer (score 21):

Use the [`instanceof`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html) operator:

```
if(a instanceof MyClass)
{
    //do something
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I agree with the use of `instanceof` already mentioned.

An additional benefit of using `instanceof` is that when used with a `null` reference `instanceof` of will return `false`, while `a.getClass()` would throw a `NullPointerException`.

Answer (score 5):

Try operator `instanceof`.

Answer (score 3):

The usual way would be:

```
if (a instanceof A)
```

However, there are cases when you can't do this, such as when `A` in a generic argument.

Due to Java's type erasure, the following won't compile:

```
<A> boolean someMethod(Object a) {
    if (a instanceof A)
    ...
}
```

and the following won't work (and will produce an `unchecked cast` warning):

```
<A> void someMethod(Object a) {
    try {
        A casted = (A)a;    
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
         ...
    }
}
```

You can't cast to `A` at runtime, because at runtime, `A` is essentially `Object`.

The solutions to such cases is to use a `Class` instead of the generic argument:

```
void someMethod(Object a, Class<A> aClass) {
    if (aClass.isInstance(a)) {
       A casted = aClass.cast(a);
       ...
    }
}
```

You can then call the method as:

```
someMethod(myInstance, MyClass.class);
someMethod(myInstance, OtherClass.class);
```