# Passing as Sub Class from array of Super Classes

Tags: java, class, processing

`Projectiles` is a arrayList of `Projectile`.
There are a couple subClasses of `Projectile` like `Laser`.
Here im trying to pass a Projectile into another function.

```
  void checkProjectiles() {

    for (int index=0; index<Projectiles.size (); index++) {
      if (sq(Projectiles.get(index).xPos - posX) + sq(Projectiles.get(index).yPos - posY) < sq(size)) { //if within the a circle radius of size from centre of roid
        Projectile checkProjectile = Projectiles.get(index);
        collision(checkProjectile);
      }
    }
  }
```

My problem is that when passing an instance of `Laser` into this function, instead of going to `collision(Laser laser)` it goes to `collision(Projectile projectile)` instead.
How do I get the object to pass as an instance of its specific subClass?

Comment: Can you have a collision method for the base class and override it in sub class. This way, whatever sub class object you passed in will call the corresponding collision method

Comment: @dragon66 This is what I actually would have liked to do. But im doing this as a class assignment and the lecturer insisted we use an overloaded method to handle this event. He told me to look up 'the visitor dilema'

Comment: Anyway, the way the answer suggested will be a maintenance nightmare when you are going to add more sub class type to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are having is that, as far as the program is concerned, everything in Projectiles can only be resolved as a Projectile, not as any of its subclasses.  There are a few ways to handle this, but the simplest, I think, is to handle it within collision.  Expect to be handed a Projectile type object and split it out within the method using the instanceof method.

See this answer for an example of comparison operators with class types.
[Check if an object belongs to a class in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4294844/check-if-an-object-belongs-to-a-class-in-)

You should read up on Polymorphism and things like Interfaces, which can also be useful.